# How to inspect QWidget tree hierarchy

Tags: qt, user-interface, qwidget

I am working on a legacy Qt application where QWidgets are added and updated dynamically, and I would like to access the QWidget tree to troubleshoot problems.

Are there any tools that enable developers to inspect the widget/window tree of a Qt application?

Comment: maybe https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dumpObjectTree

Answer (score 0):

As a Windows-only solution, Microsoft's [Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) offers a way to examine all UI elements currently in your desktop.

Even though Microsoft's [Accessibility Insights](https://accessibilityinsights.io/) is depicted as the successor of Microsoft's Inspect, Accessibility Insights is largely unusable and useless in this regard.